# 'ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddEventLog'

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to use AddEventLog for Worker Service on ASP.NET Core 3.1.3
I have installed NuGet  Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog

Problem is I am getting the error 'ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddEventLog'

Here is my code:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings()
        {
            SourceName = "MySource",
            LogName = "MyLogName"
        });
    })

    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Needs to add "using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;", it is strange that VS 2019 does not recognize the need for  "using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" at "Show potential fixes" (CTRL + .);